# Using for / list comprehension for creating a tuple from any amount of other tuples

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, robotics

With the following code I'm looking at how to create the `TRACKS[0]` and `ARM[0]` tuples (or even a whole set, e.g. `ARM`), as they are very similar - I think something like a list comprehension would work (as I'm picturing a for each loop).

```
# MOTORS: all, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5 (+, -)
MOTORS = (
  (
    (0b01010101, 0b00000001, 0b00000000),
    (0b10101010, 0b00000010, 0b00000000)
  ),
  (
    (2**0, 0, 0),
    (2**1, 0, 0)
  ),
  (
    (2**2, 0, 0),
    (2**3, 0, 0)
  ),
  (
    (2**4, 0, 0),
    (2**5, 0, 0)
  ),
  (
    (2**6, 0, 0),
    (2**7, 0, 0)
  ),
  (
    (0, 2**0, 0),
    (0, 2**1, 0)
  )
)

LED = (0,0,1)

# TRACKS: both, left, right (forward, reverse) 
TRACKS = (
    (
      (MOTORS[4][0][0] | MOTORS[5][0][0], MOTORS[4][0][1] | MOTORS[5][0][1], MOTORS[4][0][2] | MOTORS[5][0][2]),
      (MOTORS[4][1][0] | MOTORS[5][1][0], MOTORS[4][1][1] | MOTORS[5][1][1], MOTORS[4][1][2] | MOTORS[5][1][2])
    ),
    MOTORS[4],
    MOTORS[5]
  )

# ARM: all, elbow, wrist, grip (forward/open, reverse/close)  
ARM = (
  (
      (MOTORS[1][0][0] | MOTORS[2][0][0] | MOTORS[3][0][0], MOTORS[1][0][1] | MOTORS[2][0][1] | MOTORS[3][0][1], MOTORS[1][0][2] | MOTORS[2][0][2] | MOTORS[3][0][2]),
      (MOTORS[1][1][0] | MOTORS[2][1][0] | MOTORS[3][1][0], MOTORS[1][1][1] | MOTORS[2][1][1] | MOTORS[3][1][1], MOTORS[1][1][2] | MOTORS[2][1][2] | MOTORS[3][1][2])
    ),
    MOTORS[1],
    MOTORS[2],
    MOTORS[3]
  )

def motormsk (motor_id, motor_config):
  return (motor_config[motor_id][0][0] | motor_config[motor_id][1][0], motor_config[motor_id][0][1] | motor_config[motor_id][1][1], motor_config[motor_id][0][2] | motor_config[motor_id][1][2])
```

The `motormsk` function does a logical `OR` to create a mask of the values passed in and I thought that it could be used recursively to generate the mask, the function would need to take any number of tuples.

This configuration is used to interface with a USB motor control interface (as in the OWI-535 Robotic Arm Edge), that I'm adding virtual system config (`ARM` and `TRACKS`) to allow me to change them around / re-purpose them easily.

USAGE: sending `MOTORS[0][0]` starts all motors forward, `TRACKS[0][1]` starts the tracks in reverse, `TRACKS[1][0]` starts the left track forward and `motormsk(3, ARM)` stops the grip motor, etc.

There is a repl.it here: https://repl.it/@zimchaa/robo-config - Thanks.

EDIT: With a suggestion to reword and a clarification of the question I've had a go at the problem for 2 elements:

```
def motorcmb (motor_id_1, motor_dir_1, motor_id_2, motor_dir_2, motor_config):
  return (motor_config[motor_id_1][motor_dir_1][0] | motor_config[motor_id_2][motor_dir_2][0], motor_config[motor_id_1][motor_dir_1][1] | motor_config[motor_id_2][motor_dir_2][1], motor_config[motor_id_1][motor_dir_1][2] | motor_config[motor_id_2][motor_dir_2][2])
```

This produces: `motorcmb(1, 0, 2, 1, TRACKS)`

`=> (64, 2, 0)`

I'd still like to see what's possible / best practices for arbitrary numbers of elements.

Comment: Sorry, what's being asked here?

Comment: I've created, by hand the tuples `ARM` and `TRACKS` - I wondered if there's a way to generate them using list comprehension or something - the rest of the information is the why, for interested parties.

Comment: Should I rewrite the question?

Comment: I take it you want a version of `motormsk()` that would be able to handle an arbitrary number of tuples, instead of the two 3-tuples it currently handles. Am I right?

Comment: @zimchaa I'll go through your question one more time but generally yes, just not sure about your requirements

Comment: @BoarGules - yes, essentially - although `motormsk()` does something a bit more specific - a general replacement could take an arbitrary number of motor tuples, the direction (i.e. +, -) and `OR` the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `itertools.chain()` to reduce a variable number of tuples to a single sequence, and then

```
from operator import __or__
from functools import reduce 
x = reduce(__or__, myiterable)
```

to `or` them all together. I don't really understand the way your tuples are nested so I'm not going to try and go into specifics.

Comment: Thanks very much - that's a useful approach!